# Scalar potential from electric field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage

I am trying to calculate the scalar potential of a disk located at $z=0$. I determined the electric field along the $z$ axis

$$\vec{E}=\frac{\sigma}{2 \epsilon_{0}}\left[1-\frac{z}{\sqrt{z^{2}+R^{2}}}\right] \hat{z}.$$

How could you determine the scalar potential along the $z-$axis from the electric field? If $E=-\nabla V$ So should I integrate component by component? Is there a way to start determining the scalar potential and then the electric field with the same data? Here a beginner in electromagnetism.

Comment: Well this vector only has one component so the equation for V simplifies to $\vec{E}=-\frac{dV}{dz}$.

Comment: The given electric field can suggestively be written as $\vec{E} = (0,0, E_{z}(z)) = - \nabla V = - ( \partial_{x}V, \partial_{y}V, \partial_{z}V)$. Now, match components and integrate to get $V$.

Comment: Welcome to PSE. You ask for the scalar potential along the $z-$axis only ???

Answer (score 0):

$\vec{E}=-\nabla V$ means, kindly writing all the components and functional dependences explicitly,
\begin{align}
E_x (x,y,z) = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x}(x,y,z)
\,,\quad
E_y (x,y,z) = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial y} (x,y,z)
\,,\quad
E_z (x,y,z) = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial z} (x,y,z)
\,,
\end{align}
for $\vec{E}$ a function associating a vector $\vec{E} (x,y,z)$ to a point $(x,y,z)$ and $V$ a function associating a scalar $V (x,y,z)$ to a point $(x,y,z)$.
That is, $\vec{E}$ is a vector field, and $V$ is a scalar field.

Then your question boils down to
\begin{align}
&-\frac{\partial V}{\partial z} (0,0,z) = E_z(0,0,z)
= \frac{\sigma}{2\varepsilon_0}\left[1-\frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2+R^2}}\right]
\,,\\
& -\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} (0,0,z) = E_x(0,0,z)
= 0
\,,\quad -\frac{\partial V}{\partial y} (0,0,z) = E_y(0,0,z)
= 0
\,.
\end{align}
Integrating, this boils down to
\begin{align}
V(0,0,z) = \frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0} \left( \sqrt{z^2+R^2}-z\right) + c
\,,
\end{align}
where $c$ is a constant.
We can set $c=0$, demanding the potential becomes zero at infinity.
This answers your question.
If you are confused about the “integration” procedure, consider the $\vec{E}=-\nabla V$ equation in the “$dV = -\vec{E}\cdot d\vec{x}$” format:
\begin{align}
dV &= -E_x(x,y,z)\,dx - E_y(x,y,z)\,dy - E_z(x,y,z)\,dz
\\
&= -\frac{\sigma}{2\varepsilon_0}\left[1-\frac{z}{\sqrt{z^2+R^2}}\right] dz
\text{    (when restricted on the $z$ axis)}
\\
&= d\left[
\frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0} \left(\sqrt{z^2+R^2}-z\right)
\right] \text{   (when restricted on the $z$ axis)}
\,.
\end{align}

Some extra comments.
Going further, we can deduce from cylindrical symmetry and $E_x(0,0,z)=E_y(0,0,z)=0$ that in the vicinity of the point $(0,0,z)$ the potential approximately behaves as
\begin{align}
V(x,y,z) = \frac{\sigma}{2\varepsilon_0} \left( z - \sqrt{z^2+R^2}\right) + f\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)
\end{align}
with $f(s)$ a function with vanishing first-derivative at $s=0$: $f’(0)=0$.
Using the differential form of Gauss’ law $\nabla\cdot\vec{E}=0$, we can further determine the second-order term of $f(s)$.
Going even more further, the *full* solution can be obtained by using the standard Legndre polynomial technique as
\begin{align}
V(r,\theta=0) = \frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0} \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty a_\ell\frac{{r_<}^\ell}{{r_>}^{\ell+1}}
\quad\implies\quad
V(r,\theta) = \frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon_0} \sum_{\ell=0}^\infty a_\ell\frac{{r_<}^\ell}{{r_>}^{\ell+1}}\mathrm{P}_\ell(\cos\theta)
\,,
\end{align}
where $r_<$ and $r_>$ denote the smaller and the larger one among $r$ and $R$.
For this problem we have
\begin{align}
V(r,\theta=0)=
\frac{\sigma}{2\varepsilon_0} \left( r - \sqrt{r^2+R^2}\right)
= \frac{\sigma}{2\varepsilon_0} \left( r - r_> \left( 1 + \frac{{r_<}^2}{2{r_>}^2} + \cdots \right) \right)
\,.
\end{align}
I’ll leave further steps as an exercise.